# Deserializing an Object only reads one data

Tags: java, object, serialization, file-io

how do read file data from file/Deserializing an object.I have created a file which is binary file which contains list of companies data i am able to add new company and its related data but when i want to read back all the file datas it only gives first company datas and it prints null ..what is the problem below is what i have done

```
 public class CompanyInfo extends Company { 
    int counter=0;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    private ArrayList<Company> companyinfo;

public CompanyInfo() {
    companyinfo=new ArrayList<Company>();
}

public void registercompany() {

    System.out.println("Enter Company Name \n");
    companyName=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Enter Company Code \n");
    companyCode=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Enter the Share Number \n");
    shareNo=in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Enter Closing Rate \n");
    closingRate=in.nextDouble();
    Company cin=new Company(companyName,companyCode,shareNo,closingRate);
    companyinfo.add(cin);

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream outObjFile =new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("companies.dat",true));
        Company company = new Company(companyName,companyCode,shareNo,closingRate);
        outObjFile.writeObject(company);
        outObjFile.writeChars("\n");
        outObjFile.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("A file error has occurred. Sorry.");
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }


    counter++;  

    }
public void viewcompany(){
    try {
        ObjectInputStream inObjFile = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("companies.dat"));
                System.out.println(inObjFile.readObject()); // displays first object
                Company company = (Company)inObjFile.readObject(); // restores object
                System.out.println(company); // displays restored object
                inObjFile.close(); // finished with the file now.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: You are only serializing/deserialize company, if you want to get all of them you should serialize/deserialize `companyinfo`

Comment: i didn't get u sorry! could u please explain?

Comment: I'm guessing by the `append = true` flag to `FileOutputStream` that there may be an attempt to have each written value appended to the file.  However, `ObjectOutputStream`s write special marker values into the stream, so you have to do more work if you want to read multiple separate object streams out of one file.

Comment: coz i want some of the attributes of comapany in companyinfo

Comment: Are you trying to (a) serialise a single `Company` to the file, or are you (b) trying to serialise a `List<Company>` to the file, or are you (c) trying to _append_ a single `Company` to an ever growing file, and when reading back, read back all the individual serialised `Company`s as a single list?

Comment: i am trying to append a single company to an ever growing file and when reading back read all individual serialised company as a single list

Comment: You can't append to a serialized stream without making special arrangements. Have a look for a class called something like `AppendingObjectOutputStream.` Writing a newline to the file is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I will do two different ways.

1. Add all details into hashmap and serialize that object. So while reading back, I can search using "key". Key can be name or ID of company. You can do same with ArrayList as well. Search may be difficult. [Immutable collections from Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) are less memory used and more better.
2. Another solution is create object file with key.dat and put into a directory called company. So easy to read back and do search as well.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the answer ...Hope it helps to others too..good luck

```
public class CompanyInfo extends Company { 
    int counter=0;
    private static String filename = "company.dat";
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    private ArrayList<Company> companyinfo;

    public CompanyInfo() {
        companyinfo=new ArrayList<Company>();
    }

public void registercompany() {


    System.out.println("Enter Company Name \n");
    companyName=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Company Code \n");
    companyCode=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the Share Number \n");
    shareNo=in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Closing Rate");
    closingRate=in.nextDouble();
    Company cin=new Company(companyName,companyCode,shareNo,closingRate);
    companyinfo.add(cin);
File file=new File(filename);
boolean append=true;
ObjectOutputStream out=null;
try {
    if (!file.exists()||!append) {
        out=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
    }
    else
    {
        out=new AppendableObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream (filename, append));
    }
    Company company = new Company(companyName,companyCode,shareNo,closingRate);
    out.writeObject(company);
    out.flush();

} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace ();
}finally{
    try{
        if (out != null) out.close ();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}

    counter++;  

    }
public void viewcompany(){
    try {
        List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        try{
        while (true) {
        results.add(ois.readObject());}
            }
        catch (OptionalDataException e) {
            if (!e.eof) throw e; } 
        finally {
            System.out.println(results);
            //System.out.println(((Company)results.get(0)).companyName);
            ois.close(); }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
private static class AppendableObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {
    public AppendableObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
      super(out);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {}
  }
}
```